# API headers for shopify API

Tags: php, api, shopify

What are the headers needs to pass to get response from Shopify? I want shopify response with Postman. How can I get it?

I've already tried with "token" param but getting an error:

```
"{"errors":"[API] Invalid API key or access token (unrecognized login or wrong password)"}"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"X-Shopify-Access-Token" is the key of the header for that token value.